# Call to a member function insert() on string

Tags: php, laravel, intervention, gdlib

I want to add a watermark to my uploaded image using [intervention image](http://image.intervention.io/) library in laravel.I have installed it through command `composer require intervention/image` 
 , added `Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class` in providers array and `'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class` in aliases array.

This is my code sample:

```
if($request->file1)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'file1' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
        ]);
        $imageName = time().'-'.rand(11111, 99999).'.'.$request->file1->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $imageName = $imageName->insert('https://www.exabytes.my/wp-content/uploads/400x150-exabytes-logo.png','center');
        $request->file1->move('theme/img/properties', $imageName);
    }
```

Comment: So what's the question? Does it not work? In what way does it not work?

Comment: @user673679 it gives me an error:Call to a member function insert() on string

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually use the `Image` class/facade:

```
$imageName = time().'-'.rand(11111, 99999).'.'.$request->file1->getClientOriginalExtension();
$file = $request->file1->move('theme/img/properties', $imageName);
$source = 'https://www.exabytes.my/wp-content/uploads/400x150-exabytes-logo.png';
Image::make($file->getPath())->insert($source, 'center');
```

Comment: Have tried your code now it shows another error: Unable to init from given binary data.

Comment: What's the result of `dd($file->getPath());`?

Comment: Looks like a problem with your GD installation: https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/634#issuecomment-327967714